# How to observe object.property changes on an observable array with mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm using reactjs and mobx.  I have an observable array of Item objects, and I'm trying to display them and show property changes "live" by observing the properties on the objects in the array.  The changes are not triggered by a click event on any of the components, but by a response to an API call.

I understand that property changes on objects within the array will not trigger the entire list to re-render (which is good), but I can't get it to re-render the single Item component that should be observing the properties of the Item object.

I have tried a couple methods of getting the Item objects within the array to be observable, but none of these are working for me:

- calling 'extendObservable() from the Item's constructor
- assigning the props.item to a class member decorated with '@observable'
- calling the observable constructor and passing in the item object like this:   const item = observable(item)
- passing the 'hasUnreadData' field as a separate prop and making that observable via 'observable.box(item.hasUnreadData).

Here's some simplified example code (in typescript):

```
class Item {

  id : string
  hasUnreadData : boolean

  constructor (data: any) {
    this.id = data.id;
    // false by default
    this.hasUnreadData = data.hasUnreadData;
  }

}

@observable items: Item[];

// observes the array and re-renders when items are added/removed (this works)
@observer
class ItemListComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List> {
        items.map((item: Item, index) => {

          <ItemComponent key={item.id} itemModel={item} />

        }
      }
    )
  }
}

// should observe the 'hasUnreadData' flag and apply different styles when it re-renders (but this does not work, it only displays the initial state)
@observer
class ItemComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const item = this.props.item;
    return (
      <ListItem button divider selected={item.hasUnreadData} />
    )

  }
}


// imagine this is a promise from an API call
API.fetchData().then((itemId: string) => {
  itemToUpdate = items.find(i => i.id === itemId);
  itemToUpdate.hasUnreadData = true; 
  // this does not trigger the ItemComponent to render again as expected.
});
```

Do I need to clone or otherwise "re-create" the Item object to trigger render? Or am I making come kind of obvious mistake here?  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I know that this is old topic, but this is only one topic I've found, that seems like a my issue also. (I case if you still work with an old MOBX).
So this is solved my issue.
Also make sure that some wher is your application you don't use variable components, use function components instead!

```
// imagine this is a promise from an API call
API.fetchData().then((itemId: string) => {
  itemToUpdate = items.find(i => i.id === itemId);
      runInAction(() => {
              itemToUpdate.hasUnreadData = true; 
          }); 
});
```

Try to do it with `runInAction()` method from mobx